# Trying to embed some javascript into a laravel view, inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I borrowed some code to make a 3 state button. I'm trying to make one button for each of the vowels. First one does its job, the other ones don't seem to change color. I don't know how to fix this.

I've tried moving the foreach loop up and down but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
@foreach ($vocales as $vocal)
<div class="p-1 d-inline-block">
    <div class="btn-group-toggle d-inline" data-toggle="buttons">
        <input type="radio" name="high" value="2" checked hidden>
        <input type="radio" name="high" value="1" hidden>
        <input type="radio" name="high" value="0" hidden>
        <button type="button" id="toggler" class="btn btn-secondary">{{$vocal}}</button>
    </div>
    <div id='result'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="high"]');
        $('#result').html($radios.filter(':checked').val());
        $('#toggler').click(function() {
            var colorClasses = ["btn-danger", "btn-success", "btn-secondary"];
            var $checked = $radios.filter(':checked');
            var $next = $radios.eq($radios.index($checked) + 1);
            if (!$next.length) {
                $next = $radios.first();
            }
            $next.prop("checked", true);
            var newValue = $radios.filter(':checked').val();

            $(this)
            .removeClass(colorClasses.join(" "))
            .addClass(colorClasses[newValue]);

            $('#result').html(newValue);
        });
    </script>
</div>
@endforeach
```

If you can make this work I'd be extremely grateful

Answer (score 1):

Each #result must have a unique identifier, for example # result-1 # result-2, etc. In js scripts as well. The error is that the first element is changed and the subsequent ones are ignored.